# netstat multiple local addresses - connections from other PC in LAN to Internet

Tags: ubuntu, networking, lan, netstat

Running netstat on my Ubuntu 12.04 in a LAN reveals entries like this:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State  
tcp        0      0 other-pc-in-lan-hostname.lo:44790    xx.xx.xx.xx:http     VERBUNDEN  
tcp        1      0 my-lan-hostname.lo:51875 mulberry.canonical:http CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        0      0 other-pc-in-lan-hostname.lo:47235    xx.xx.xx.xx:http      VERBUNDEN  
tcp        0      0 my-lan-hostname.lo:38583 xx.xx.xx.xx:http VERBUNDEN  
tcp        0      0 other-pc-in-lan-hostname.lo:44791    xx.xx.xx.xx:http     VERBUNDEN
```

It basically shows (or it seems to show) connections which are open from another PC (also running Ubuntu 12.04) in my LAN to the Internet. I have only one hostname set and only a single interface active.

Do I misunderstand netstats output?